# How to post url encoded json data and get response data back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have been trying to post URL-encoded data using below code snippet

```
$.post( "url",{param:"value"},function(data){
   alert("data==="+data);
});
```

Here URL is a `restful API` URL
This one is not working. Then I tried with `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
  url:"url",
  type:"POST",
  dataType:"application/json",
  contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  data:$.param( $(param:'value') ),
  success:function(data){
   alert("data==="+data);
  }
});
```

still not able to get data using a demo.html page

Then later tried with `PostMan` with the same configuration and it was working fine with the desired `json` result.

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax has a `success` param in the passed object.

To send `json` use `dataType: 'json'`.
No need for contentType, really.

Here's your updated code:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"url",
  type:"POST",
  dataType:"json",
  data:{param:'value'},

  success: function( data ) 
  {
   alert("data==="+data);
  }
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is wrong,

```
$.ajax({
  url: "URL",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "xml/html/script/json", // format for response
  contentType: "application/json", // send as JSON
  data: $.param( $(param:'value') ),

  complete: function(data) {
    //called when complete
    console.log(data);
  },

  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    console.log(data);
 },

  error: function(err) {
    //called when there is an error
    console.log(err);
  },
});
```

This is a full Ajax function.

Comment: where to define this complete, success & error function. Do we need to send extra parameter on button click.

Comment: No. This is a complete code for making an Ajax request... the functions are defined already, inside the body of the function you can handle the data returned by the call. See my edited answer.